# not able to update logo on google oauth consent screen

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-console

I tried to update the logo on google oauth consent screen about a month ago, the app shows verification status as verified and when I click the "edit app" button it shows the updated logo there(from last 30 days). But when I go to oauth consent screen page it shows old logo.

My web-app uses sub-domains e.g. the sub_domain.main_domain.com for different clients.

Can anyone help me on this

I udpated the logo and then submitted the app for verification and its verified

Comment: I would question weather or not you are updating the correct project.

Comment: I am updating the correct project because I only have 1 project